# Regex to disallow all Special Chars but allow German Umlauts in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to allow all Alphanumeric Characters and disallow all Special Characters in a RegEx. But I would like to allow German Umlauts but becouse they are Special Chars too, I can't type them in. I use this Script:

```
    if(website_media_description.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g)) { 

    alert('Found Special Char');        

}
```

So when a äöüÄÖÜß is in the variable than I get the alert too. I also tryed this Script:

```
    if(website_media_description.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]/g)) { 

    alert('Found Special Char');        

}
```

But this also does not work. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you need to use the unicode representations of them...like `\u2345` or whatever

Comment: give us your test string.

Comment: it seems to work fine in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWdq2/)

Comment: `'ü'.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]/g); // null`

Comment: Hi, my test String comes from an input field, i write "description test 1 öäüÖÄÜß". Thanks :) In your example it works, then why not on my Website?

Comment: @Thorsten it is matching the spaces

Comment: But why not on my Website?

Comment: @Ian: You where right, for some reason i needed to use the Unicode representation [^a-zA-Z0-9\u00E4\u00F6\u00FC\u00C4\u00D6\u00DC\u00df]. Thanks :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> my test String comes from an input field, i write "description test 1 öäüÖÄÜß"

Your problem is coming from the fact you haven't considered every character you want in your whitelist.

Let's consider what is actually matched by your test string

```
"description test 1 öäüÖÄÜß".match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]/g);
// [" ", " ", " "]
```

As we can see, it matched 3 times, and each time was whitespace. So, the solution is to add a space to your whitelist (assuming you don't want to allow tab/return etc).

```
"description test 1 öäüÖÄÜß".match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß ]/g);
// null
```

Your test string now passes the *RegExp* without a match, which means it is valid in this case.

Comment: Hi :) I removed the whitespaces now and it still does not work. Do you know what could else wrong? Thanks :) I tested it on my Website and it does not work, but in the Fiddle it does. I don`t know what i can do wrong now. I would be happy if anyone has an idea! Thanks :)

Comment: For some reason i needed to use the Unicode representation [^a-zA-Z0-9\u00E4\u00F6\u00FC\u00C4\u00D6\u00DC\u00df]. Thanks :)

Comment: @Thorsten sounds like you're mixing character encodings on your page. Put everything in _UTF-8_ and send the correct headers.

Answer (score 8):

For some reason I needed to use the unicode representation:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\u00E4\u00F6\u00FC\u00C4\u00D6\u00DC\u00df]`
```

Thanks to everyone :)

Comment: I might have an explaination: the source file encoding differs from the servers (if you use templates) or the client side by wich I mean JavaScript for example. It is a good practice to use Unicode, a bit hacky but the most portable.

Comment: this should be the answer, the accepted one does not work and in typescript its: [\\w\u00E4\u00F6\u00FC\u00C4\u00D6\u00DC\u00df]