# Regex for Umlaut

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

I am using JS Animated Contact Form with this line of validation regex:

```
rx:{".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'}, other fields...
```

I just found out, that I can't enter name like "Müller". The regex will not accept this. What do I have to do, to allow also Umlauts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17153545/2563028

Comment: you could use `\w` as 'word', but you'll have to test if that mathces the umlaut

Comment: In my test, `\w` did not catch umlauts.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You should use in your regex unicode codes for characters, like `\u0080`.
For German language, I found following table:

```
Zeichen     Unicode
------------------------------
Ä, ä        \u00c4, \u00e4
Ö, ö        \u00d6, \u00f6
Ü, ü        \u00dc, \u00fc
ß           \u00df
```

(source http://javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=java:unicode)

Comment: [The holy grail](http://unicode-table.com/en). You can also write ranges, ie. `[\u00F0-\u02AF]`.

Comment: Use this to find hidden characters except German Umlaute: https://regexr.com/4pmml

Comment: in case you are using PHP use `[\x{00F0}-\x{02AF}]`

Answer (score 27):

Try using this:

```
/^[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z'][\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z-' ]+[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z']?$/
```

I have added the unicode range `\u00C0-\u017F` to the start of each of the square bracket groups.

Given that `/^[\u00C0-\u017FA-Za-z]+$/.test("aeiouçéüß")` returns `true`, I expect it should work.

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550799/940252.

Comment: `[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z']?`$/ is kind of redundant, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure as I'm not terribly hot on regex and the OP didn't specify the pattern they're hoping to match. I just worked with their original code. If you can clean it up please do! :)

Comment: I would venture to change that space to something else to capture all non-word characters like hyphens. Here's a test: https://regex101.com/r/zH5uV0/4

Comment: `/^[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z'][\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z-' ]+[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z']?$/.test("ü") -> false`

Answer (score 14):

In JS, you can use the `u` flag on regular expressions to enable access to a special "meta sequence", namely `\p`. `\p` is a Unicode aware lookup that has a special `Letter` category. This category will match German, Swedish, Scandinavian, cyrillic characters etc.

In short, use this:

```js
/\p{Letter}/u
```

Props to [this article](https://dev.to/tillsanders/let-s-stop-using-a-za-z-4a0m) by Till Sanders.

Answer (score 8):

I came up with a combination of different ranges:

```
[A-Za-zÀ-ž\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF]
```

- [Diacritical Marks: [À-ž]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44586972/1584876)
- [Greek and Coptic:
  [\u0370-\u03FF]](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_greek.asp)
- [Cyrillic: [\u0400-\u04FF]](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_cyrillic.asp)

But I see that it misses some letters of  @SambitD proposal, refer to: https://rubular.com/r/2g00QJK4rBS8Y4

Answer (score 4):

I used

> A-Za-z-ÁÀȦÂÄǞǍĂĀÃÅǺǼǢĆĊĈČĎḌḐḒÉÈĖÊËĚĔĒẼE̊ẸǴĠĜǦĞG̃ĢĤḤáàȧâäǟǎăāãåǻǽǣćċĉčďḍḑḓéèėêëěĕēẽe̊ẹǵġĝǧğg̃ģĥḥÍÌİÎÏǏĬĪĨỊĴĶǨĹĻĽĿḼM̂M̄ʼNŃN̂ṄN̈ŇN̄ÑŅṊÓÒȮȰÔÖȪǑŎŌÕȬŐỌǾƠíìiîïǐĭīĩịĵķǩĺļľŀḽm̂m̄ŉńn̂ṅn̈ňn̄ñņṋóòôȯȱöȫǒŏōõȭőọǿơP̄ŔŘŖŚŜṠŠȘṢŤȚṬṰÚÙÛÜǓŬŪŨŰŮỤẂẀŴẄÝỲŶŸȲỸŹŻŽẒǮp̄ŕřŗśŝṡšşṣťțṭṱúùûüǔŭūũűůụẃẁŵẅýỳŷÿȳỹźżžẓǯßœŒçÇ

which supports almost all the chars in Europe.
[Source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin-script_alphabets)

Comment: No sane programmer would list all characters, when there are shorthand character classes and ranges. Please, don't do that.

Comment: @user1438038: well, I actually would prefer listing the characters explicitly in some use cases because you can have unwanted characters in the ranges, and this way you see them all imediately - definitely good in unit tests code. isambitd: this range is missing ąęł - which means it doesn't support Polish

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the \uXXXX approach is, that it is not supported by all Regex flavours. For example Visual C++ does not support it.
There, you would need to enumerate the actual letters.

I recommend to use a tool like https://www.regexbuddy.com/ that knows as many flavors as possible.