# Match Regular Expression German Language

Tags: javascript, regex

I use two Regular Expressions to Match a Text.

```
var RegExp = /[^\W\d](\w|[-'](?=\w))*/gi;
var RegExpOthers = /[^\W\d]{4,}(\w|[-']{1,2}(?=\w))*/gi;
```

Currently no Word containing letters like ä, ü, ö...(German alphabet) will be matched.

How can I extend these Expressions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for Umlaut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017723/regex-for-umlaut), and see also [Javascript + Unicode regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
[^\x00-\x7F]+
```

It matches any character which is not contained in the [ASCII character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (0-127, i.e. 0x0 to 0x7F). You can do the same thing with Unicode:

```
[^\u0000-\u007F]+
```

Comment: I´ve tried to this...If I use the Expression var RegExp = /[^\W\d]+[^\x00-\x7F](\w|[-'](?=\w))*/gi; it returns for the string "der schöne baum ist schön" only "schön" and "schöne"

Comment: You can add all the possible characters

Comment: complete list [german character](http://homepages.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~george/ansi_ascii_character_chart.html)

Comment: sorry, I have to ask again: If I use the RegExp mentioned in my comment, why does it not return the words 'der', 'baum' and 'ist', and only "schön" and "schöne" I think, I have an syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

This is subject of **Unicode** characters.

What happens is that `ä, ü, ö..` in your example is not a single letter but 2 because the tilde counts as a character as well. This brings lots of complexities and rules that needs to be followed in order to meet Unicode rules.

You could do something like: `([\x{0049}-\x{0130}])` to meet for example *i* with tildes but this expression may vary depending if you are going to use this expression on .net, java, javascript or php.

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lL8zN5)

You could also check what code each character represents here:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%C4%B0&preview=entity