# Generic regex umlaut solution?

Tags: c++, regex, qt

Is there a generic (non-)word regex that covers all mutations of characters on this globe? I am developing an application that should handle all languages. 
Technically I want to split sentences by words. Splitting them by nonword characters (\W) splits by 'ä' too. A [static workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017723/regex-for-umlaut) is not an option since and explicitely covering all mutations on this world (éçḮñ and thousands more)  is impossible.

Comment: So, it is JavaScript? Use XRegExp `[^\pL]` or `\PL`.

Comment: Why don't you split by `\s` ? Could you provide input & desired output ?

Comment: So you want to split `it's` into `it` and `s`? Wouldn't it make sense to split on whitespace and non-connecting punctuation? At any rate, you definitely need to tell us which regex engine you're using.

Comment: No its a C++/Qt application. I want to index words. So splitting by space is not optimal too, because of punctuation marks. But a static set of separators is indeed a better approach. This solves almost my problem, thank you, but not the SO question.

Comment: Do you mean "umlaut" (which is specifically the mark in the German characters ä, ö‚ and ü) or any accent (ie  ̈ ,  ̂,etc)  or any accented character (Ö, ê, ñ etc)?

Comment: I mean any diacritic signs or more general any mutations that do not fit in `[A-Za-z]` but are word characters (in a natural interpretation)

Comment: There are languages where the characters look like they have diacritic marks but are in fact considered actual letters in the alphabet. I think in Swedish for example, the letters `å`, `ä` and `ö` are considered distinct letters, not letters with diacritic marks (I could be wrong there but I remember there is a language like that).

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you something that will work on all languages because I don't know enough languages to judge whether there will be edge cases.

My suggestion:

1. Split on whitespace (`\s+`).
2. Trim punctuation characters from start/end of each "word" you got in step 1 (replace `^\p{P}+|\p{P}+$` with nothing - the [QRegularExpression docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html) say that it supports Unicode fully, so there's hope this will work)

Unless you care about preserving punctuation in examples like `This is Charles' car`, this should go a long way without removing punctuation within words like `it's` or `Marne-sur-Seine`.