# Check String Only Contain Characters

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I know this has been asked before, but my code isn't working.

The senario is I need to check if a string ONLY contains letters, numbers and spaces. I need to fail if it contains any thing else.

I've tried the RegEx method, but I don't understand regular expressions, so I need to use a LINQ method for my assessment.

Here is my code:

```
if (!CSVItemArray[count].All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit) && !CSVItemArray[count].Contains(" "))
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is `CSVItemArray` an array of strings?

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, it is.

Comment: *so I need to use a LINQ method for my assessment*... What does LINQ have to do with checking for character types?

Comment: You should really try to consider regular expression here, which will be much more clear to you once you will be used to it. In this particular case "/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/" would be enough. 

You can have a look at http://regexr.com/ for example. You will find  tutorial, help, samples and online test of your expressions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing something (e.g. using Regex) because not understanding it is a bad thing - at least for developers. In particular if what you want to do can easily be achieved by using a regex.

Having said this you may simply use this:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[A-Za-z0-9\\s]*$");
var valid = r.IsMatch(myString);
```

This will look for any number of upper- or lowercase characters, digits and whitespace-characters. The sequence itself is embraced by `[]`, the following `*` sets the number of times the sequence can occur in the string (in your case none uo to infinite times). The `^` and `$` are just for marking the start and end of your string repsectivly.  This avoids that `%asdfgh12345   //` will match for instance.

EDIT: If you need Umlauts also (ä, ö, ü, ß, ...) you may have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017723/regex-for-umlaut) which handles special characters also.

Comment: Good point. Thoug your regex does not include äöüß and those letters. But OP didn't specify what makes a letter for him.

Comment: @HimBromBeere _"Doing something [...] because not understanding it is a bad thing..."_ I definitely agree with that.
I will learn how Regex works, but if I use it in my assessment, I'll have to explain what it's doing, and my tutor hasn't taught me that, so it wouldn't go down well.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I've realised what one of my issues is right now. I'm using the regex for now.
My code fails when it checks a string with an apostrophe. How I include that in this? `"^[A-Za-z0-9\\s]*$"`

Comment: Simply put it into the braces: `A-Za-z0-9´\\s`. If you need more special characters you should add those to your questions so that others also have the chance to edit their answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just combine the check for letter, digit, or whitespace in the `All` query:

```
if (!CSVItemArray[count].All(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)))
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is a little confused. The following returns `true` if the string in `CSVItemArray[count]` only contains letters, digits and white spaces:

```
return CSVItemArray[count].All(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
```

Comment: It is a boolean validation function, if it fails to meet my condition, it returns false.

Comment: @Smithy yes that's what it does. I said it returns true if it contains _"only letters, digits and spaces"_, so it returns falls if there is something different than that. The code checks that _`All`_ characters inside the string are letters, digits or spaces.