# How can I found and replace umlauts in filenames?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, filenames

I have a regex to found charakters in a string:

```
^[A-Za-züäöÜÄÖ$@ß€0-9\.\-_ \&\<\>\=\`\:#\{\}\,\(\)\"\'\+\]\[\/%;!?\\\n]{0,20000}$
```

When I become a name with js from a file like 'tüst.txt' the regex not match the 'ü' in the string.

How can I found the 'ü' in the filename? Or the other umlauts?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22017800/7431860) suggests using unicode characters instead of actually putting an umlaut into your regex. Its unicode is `\u00fc` - the linked answer includes a table of other common german characters, and a comment on that answer includes a link to a [unicode table.](https://unicode-table.com/en/)

There's a lot you can do with unicode in javascript - [it's worth reading more about!](https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/)