# Optimize group of characters for a cleaner code

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help whit the optimization of this group of characters `[qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ]` obviously it is really big so I need it smaller so I can use it into a regex, like this:

```
let N = /^N1\d{14}[^qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ]{78}$/;
```

I tried examples from other sites and this one too but didn't work as expected, can some one help me?

This regex is supposed to match a type of register like this one:

**Register**

```
N108258594000135255240708     315370        BLABLA BLABLABL BLAB BLA
```

Comment: What does the expression's length have to do with it working or not?

Comment: Describe in plain language what the regex is supposed to match.

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017723/regex-for-umlaut

Comment: Please indicate which language or tool you're using. There are many different flavors of regex, some of which have built-in character sets for this sort of thing.

Comment: For starters `a-z` could be used to replace `qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm`

Comment: I edited it thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Why are you negating the character group ? Isn't it better to enumerate the characters that **can** appear instead of those that mustn't ?

This would be a much cleaner regex:

```
let N = /^N1\d{14}[ 0-9A-Z]{78}$/;
```

Comment: Because those 78 must be all in uppercase and without any type of accentuation or lowercase, but especifically ```can't``` match ```those``` characters

Comment: @Lagaggio Yes, just because they must be all uppercase without accentuation or lowercase, my solution is better. It does allow only uppercase letters, numbers and spaces. It is impossible to enumerate all accentuated letters. Look into Unicode...

Comment: But is it going to allow me to introduce a ```?```, ```|``` or a ```!``` ?