# Regexp_replace collides with German umlaut ü, ö, ä

Tags: sql, macros, uppercase, regexp-replace, dbt

I am writing a macro in dbt with SQL to clean names. I elegantly wanted to upper the first letter of the names but my

```
regexp_replace('(\w)(\w*)', x -> upper(x[1]) || lower(x[2])
```

collides with the German umlauts ä, ö, ü

So for example the last name schöneberger with my regex expression from above becomes SchöNeberger and not Schöneberger.

Does someone know what to write so I can upper Schöneberger and other name with umlauts as well?

Comment: Is this a SQL _language_ related question? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Yes, it is SQL related. I am using dbt.

Comment: jarlh was asking what database is this? What you shared is very strange syntax for regexp_replace()

Comment: The data lives in AWS Athena.

Comment: You will need to tweak your regex to add unicode for the umlauts. Here's a SO question around that, hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017723/regex-for-umlaut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions.html) uses [Trino](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html) syntax, which uses Java regex syntax. Java supports the extended character classes using Unicode properties from Perl, including `\p{L}`, which is basically "any Unicode letter." So this will work for you:

```sql
regexp_replace(name_col, '(\p{L})(\p{L}*)', x -> upper(x[1]) || lower(x[2]))
```

Proof: https://regex101.com/r/N84wjS/2